# Cant do work Propel Match validators

Tags: preg-match, propel

Im developing a CRUD application. I use Propel as ORM, and added validate rules into the schema.xml. But this, not work fine.
For example, i send a string that contains a user lastname, and the validator is:

```
<rule name='minLength' value='4'/>
<rule name='maxLength' value='30'/>
<rule name='notMatch' value='/^\s+$/' />
<!-- the name can be only chars and spaces -->
<rule name='match' value='/[^A-Za-z ]$/'/>
```

The user lastname sent was: 'Martinez D Elia'. And the valid fails on 4th rule.
Any idea ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is wrong. The correct match is:

```
^[A-Za-z ]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to the previous answer, since you want a minimum of 4 characters and a max of 30, you may want to use this:

```
/^[A-Za-z ]{4,30}$/
```

Also note that you do need the "/" before and after the regular expression. And FYI, your regex was wrong for two reasons: the placement of the "^" inside of the character class and the missing length qualifier after the character class (without either the "*", "+", or brackets {}, you only match one single characters, any more will fail).